# Is there any Managment API for Azure VM location?

Tags: azure

We analyzed the managment APIs but we are not able to find an API for finding a Azure VM location.Azure VM location is equivalent to its cloud service location?

Answer (score 1):

Since to create a Virtual Machine Windows Azure automatically creates a cloud service (and hosts that VM in that), you could make use of [`Get Hosted Service Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx) functionality to find the location and that would be the location of your VM. If you created a VM using a location, then this should be sufficient.

However if you created a VM using an affinity group, you won't get location in that API call but you'll get an affinity group. In this case, you can call [`Get Affinity Group Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460789.aspx) and get the location of that affinity group and that would be the location of your VM.